# TDI systems of integral polyhedron

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

There is a theorem by Giles and Pullybank that states the following:

"For each rational polyhedron $P$ there exists a rational TDI-system $Ax \leq b$ with $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and $P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax \leq b \}$. The
vector $b$ can be chosen to be integral if and only if $P$ is integral."

Why can't we choose $b$ to be integral no matter what? If its rational I can just rescale the whole inequality by all the denominators. Does this destroy the TDI property of the equation perhaps?

Comment: No question is stupid here ... certainly not your question! It is good to make your titles searchable and relevant to your post

Comment: Thank you, youre right. Excuse me.

Comment: It probably destroys the TDI property, but since you haven't defined your terms, or even said what the acronym is for, we can't be sure.

Comment: A system of inequalities $Ax \leq b$ is said to be totally dual integral (TDI) iff the linear program $\max \{ c^tx : Ax \leq b \} $ has an integer optimal solution whenever $c$ is integral and the LP is feasible and bounded.